# 1 server 2 clients java

Tags: java, multithreading, webserver, udp, client

i want to make a game with 2 players .i will use udp server and 2 clients and i dont 
know how to connect 2 clients to 1 server at the same time and how they will communicate.
I will use only java.At last how the mouse click will syncronize with server

```
  public void mousePressed(MouseEvent event) { 
  }  
  public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent event) { 
  }  
  public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent event) { 
  }  
  public void mouseExited(MouseEvent event) { 
  }
```

the server

```
public class Provider {
public ServerSocket providerSocket;
Socket connection = null;
ObjectOutputStream out;
ObjectInputStream in;
String message;
String[] torino={"null","null"};
Provider() {}
void run()
{
    try {
        //1. creating a server socket (8080=port , 2 =number of connections)
        providerSocket = new ServerSocket(8080, 2 );
        //2. Wait for connection
        System.out.println("Waiting for connection");
        connection = providerSocket.accept();
        System.out.println("Connection received from " + connection.getInetAddress().getHostName());
        //3. get Input and Output streams
        out = new ObjectOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());
        // flush= clean the object out
        out.flush();
        in = new ObjectInputStream(connection.getInputStream());
        sendMessage("Connection successful");
        //4. The two parts communicate via the input and output streams
        try {
            //take the message from client
            message = (String)in.readObject();
            if (torino[0]=="null") 
                torino[0]=message;
            } else if (torino[1]=="null") {
                torino[1]=message;              
            }
        }
        catch(ClassNotFoundException classnot) {
            System.err.println("Data received in unknown format");
        }
    } catch(IOException ioException) {
        ioException.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally {
        //4: Closing connection
        try {
            in.close();
            out.close();
            providerSocket.close();
        } catch(IOException ioException) {
            ioException.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
//method to send messages from server to clients
void sendMessage(String msg)
{
    try {
        out.writeObject(msg);
        out.flush();
        System.out.println("server>" + msg);
    }
    catch(IOException ioException) {
        ioException.printStackTrace();
    }
}

//main method
public static void main(String args[])
{
    Provider server = new Provider();
    while(true) {
        server.run();
    }
}
```

Comment: Really the problem is on the server side of things. What does your server that can only connect with one client look like? That needs to be modified.

Comment: do you have any example?

Comment: Do *you* have an example? What did you write so far? What problems are you having? You need to start, follow a tutorial, do some searches etc. When you hot a block we can assist you by pointing you in the right direction. Your question is too vague to get proper answers here.

Comment: first i need to connect the server with other 2 pcs with different ip

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So now you can see in your code that you have a point where the server socket is waiting for a connection. That is the accept() method. At that point, you need to create a new Thread for handling the connection and let the main thread continue waiting for another connection. You may want to keep track of the number of connections made in a variable, say numConnections.

```
 while(numConnections < 2){
       connection = providerSocket.accept();
       Thread t = new Thread(new ConnectionHandler(connection));
       t.start();
       numConnections++;
 }
```

Now you ConnectionHandler class will do the work of the connection:

```
 class ConnectionHandler implements Runnable{
        Socket connection;
        public ConnectionHandler(Socket connection){
             this.connection = connection;
        }

        public void run(){
           //here you do all the code associated with handling the connection
           //such as your Object Streams and so on.
        }
 }
```

A quick Google search turns up many tutorials and examples of doing this such as this [one](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-multithreaded-servers/multithreaded-server.html). There are also some YouTude videos. You may want to start with one of those.